# Stable rank one and corners of $C^\ast$-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras, algebraic-k-theory

Thanks to a result of Herman and Vaserstein in [[3](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01388839)], Rieffel's notion of stable rank [[4](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-46.2.301)] coincides with the Bass stable rank [[1](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1964__22__5_0/?source=BSMF_1962__90__323_0)] for every $C^\ast$-algebra $A$: we denote it by $\mathrm{sr}(A)$ and we simply call it the *stable rank* of $A$.

The following fact yields a convenient characterization of the stable rank one case.

**Lemma (folklore I suppose)** A $C^\ast$-algebra has **stable rank one** if and only if the invertible elements are dense in $\widetilde{A}$, where $\widetilde{A}$ denotes $A$ if it is unital, and the unitization $A\oplus\mathbb{C}1$ of $A$ otherwise. For short, denoting the group of all invertible elements in $\widetilde{A}$ by $G\left(\widetilde{A}\right)$, we have:
$$\mathrm{sr}(A)=1\quad \Leftrightarrow\quad\overline{G\left(\widetilde{A}\right)}=\widetilde{A}.$$

Now here are the facts I'm interested in.
They deal with the stable rank of the corners $pAp$ of a given $C^\ast$-algebra $A$.

**Proposition (Corollary V.3.1.18 in [[2](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-28517-2)])** Let $A$ be a unital $C^\ast$-algebra and $p$ a full projection in $A$ (i.e. the closed ideal of $A$ generated by $p$ is all of $A$).

1. We have $\mathrm{sr}(pAp)\ge\mathrm{sr}(A)$.
2. If $\mathrm{sr}(A)<\infty$, then $\mathrm{sr}(pAp)<\infty$ and $$\mathrm{sr}(A)=1\quad \Leftrightarrow\quad\mathrm{sr}(pAp)=1.$$

What if we remove the assumption that $p$ is full?

- **Question A:** What are the known examples of $C^\ast$-algebras $A$ and projections $p\in A\setminus\{0,1\}$ such that
  $$\mathrm{sr}(A)=1<\mathrm{sr}(pAp)?$$
- **Question B:** What are the known examples of unital $C^\ast$-algebras $A$ and projections $p\in A\setminus\{0,1\}$ such that
  $$\mathrm{sr}(A)=1<\min\{\mathrm{sr}(pAp),\mathrm{sr}((1-p)A(1-p))\}?$$

[[1]](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1964__22__5_0/?source=BSMF_1962__90__323_0) H. Bass, K-theory and stable algebra, Publications Mathématiques de l’IHÉS 22 (1964), pp. 5–60.

[[2]](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-28517-2) B. Blackadar, *Operator Algebras*, Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences 122 (2006), Springer, pp. 444-452.

[[3]](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01388839) R. Herman and L. N. Vaserstein, *The stable range of $C^\ast$-algebras*, Inventiones Mathematicae 77 (1984) pp. 553-555.

[[4]](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-46.2.301) M. A. Rieffel, *Dimension and stable rank in the K-theory of $C^\ast$-algebras*, Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society 46 (1983), pp. 301–333.

Comment: If you are able to view the remarks after the proof of Corollary V.3.18 then they mention explicit counterexamples to parts of that corollary for non-full projections: e.g. taking p to be a finite-rank projection in A=B(H); or taking p to be projection onto the first co-ordinate in ${\mathbb C} \oplus {\mathcal O}_2$. I think these already give counterexamples to your Question A, but maybe I have misread/misunderstood?

Comment: @YemonChoi I am asking for examples where A has stable rank one, which implies that A be (stably) finite. Now $B(H)$ and the Cuntz algebras are infinite.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I wasn't reading carefully. [I have also deleted another comment which arose from not thinking carefully]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For separable $C^\ast$-algebras this phenomenon cannot happen, since any corner of a separable stable rank one $C^\ast$-algebra has stable rank one. More generally, this holds for $C^\ast$-algebras $A$ such that all its two-sided closed ideals are $\sigma$-unital.

In fact, suppose $A$ is separable and has stable rank one. Then all of its two-sided closed ideals have stable rank one [4, Theorem 4.4]. By Brown's stable isomorphism theorem (L. G. Brown, Stable isomorphism of hereditary subalgebras of C∗-algebras, Pacific J. Math 71 (1977), 335-348.), any corner $B$ of $A$ is stably isomorphic to the two-sided closed ideal in $A$ generated by $B$. As stable rank one is preserved by stable isomorphism [4, Theorem 3.6], any corner of $A$ has stable rank one.

Comment: Hi Jamie: I had a very quick look at Brown's paper and the main results seem to be stated for full corners (stronger condition) but get stable isomorphism to A itself (stronger conclusion). Could you maybe add some clarification about how one gets from those result to the one stated in your answer?

Comment: Hi Yemon, I extended it a tiny bit, but could go into more details if you think that would help?

Comment: Oh that makes sense now. I think I see what's going on now, although of course if the OP wants more details they can let us know.

Comment: @JamieGabe Thank you for the reference. So you're saying that if $A$ is a separable $C^\ast$-algebra with stable rank one, then $pAp$ has stable rank one for every nonzero projection $p$ (without assuming that $p$ is full), right? And this leaves Questions A and B open, right?

Comment: Separability is not important here. We can use  Proposition 4.1 of Blackadar's "The stable rank of full corners in C*-algebras" to get that if $sr(A)=1$ then $sr(pAp)=1$ for any projection $p$ in $A$.

Comment: @LeonelRobert Thanks a lot for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a community wiki answer based on [Leonel Robert's
comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381637/stable-rank-one-and-corners-of-c-ast-algebras#comment983614_381703)
to [Jamie Gabe's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/381703/14094), to
answer the question in general for arbitrary Banach
algebras.

Given the lemma established below, the answer to questions A and B is the same: there can't exist such an algebra, as spotted by Jamie Gabe in the separable case.

Immitating the argument given by Bruce Blackadar to prove Proposition 4.1 in [[1](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-04-07148-5)] (thanks to Leonel Robert for the reference), which itself mimicks Marc Rieffel's proof of Lemma 3.4 in [[2](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-46.2.301)], we obtain the following property in the more general setting of Banach algebras, without assuming that $p$ be full.

**Lemma:** Let $A$ be a Banach algebra with identity element, and let $p$ be an idempotent in $A$.

If the invertible elements are dense in $A$, then the invertible elements are dense in $pAp$.

**Proof:** Let $x\in pAp$ and let
$$0<\eta<\frac{1}{\|p^\perp\|^2}.$$
We are going to work with the 2x2 Peirce decomposition of
$$A=pAp\oplus pAp^\perp\oplus p^\perp Ap\oplus p^\perp Ap^\perp$$
with respect to $p$ and $p^\perp:=1-p$.

By assumption, we can find an invertible element
$$y=\begin{bmatrix}pyp&pyp^\perp\\p^\perp yp&p^\perp yp^\perp\end{bmatrix}\in A$$
which approximates
$$x+p^\perp=\begin{bmatrix}x&0\\0&p^\perp\end{bmatrix}$$
within $\eta$, i.e. $\|z\|\le\eta$ with $z:=x+p^\perp-y$, so that

1. $\|x-pyp\|=\|pzp\|\le\eta\|p\|^2$;
2. $\|pyp^\perp\|=\|pzp^\perp\|\le\eta\|p\|\|p^\perp\|$;
3. $\|p^\perp yp\|=\|p^\perp zp\|\le\eta\|p\|\|p^\perp\|$;
4. $\|p^\perp yp^\perp-p^\perp\|=\|p^\perp zp^\perp\|\le\eta\|p^\perp\|^2$.

By 4, we see that $p^\perp yp^\perp$ is invertible in $p^\perp Ap^\perp$ with inverse $\delta$ such that
$$\|\delta\|=\left\|\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(p^\perp-p^\perp yp^\perp\right)^n\right\|\le\frac{1}{1-\eta\|p^\perp\|^2}.$$
Using the fact that
$$\delta\cdot p^\perp yp^\perp=p^\perp yp^\perp\cdot\delta=p^\perp$$
and a routine 2x2 matrix computation, we obtain the following formula:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}p&-pyp^\perp\delta\\0&p^\perp\end{bmatrix}y
\begin{bmatrix}p&0\\-\delta p^\perp yp&p^\perp\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}pyp-(pyp^\perp)\delta(p^\perp yp)&0\\0&*\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Since $pyp^\perp\delta$ and $\delta p^\perp yp$ are nilpotent, the three elements on the left are invertible in $A$, and it follows that
$$\alpha:=pyp-(pyp^\perp)\delta(p^\perp yp)$$
is invertible in $pAp$.
It only remains to check that the above estimates yield
\begin{align*}
\|x-\alpha\|&\le\|x-pyp\|+(pyp^\perp)\delta(p^\perp yp)\\
&\le\eta\|p\|^2+\frac{\eta^2\|p\|^2\|p^\perp\|^2}{1-\eta\|p^\perp\|^2}\\
&=\frac{\eta\|p\|^2}{1-\eta\|p^\perp\|^2}.
\end{align*}
Since this upper bound tends to $0$ when $\eta\rightarrow 0$, the result follows.

**QED**

[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-04-07148-5) Bruce Blackadar, *The stable rank of full corners in $C^\ast$-algebras*, Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 132 (2004), pp. 2945–2950.

[[2]](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-46.2.301) Marc A. Rieffel, *Dimension and stable rank in the K-theory of $C^\ast$-algebras*, Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society 46 (1983), pp. 301–333.